# template class wrapping a arbitrary type/non-type template class

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a template class `base` and a class `wrapper` which contains a instantiated member of `base`. I would like to define the class `wrapper` such that it depends on a template parameter pack, which is simply "passed" to the instantiated member of `base`.

For example consider the following code, which works fine.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i, int j>
struct base {
  base()
  {
    std::cout << "i is " << i;
    std::cout << " j is " << j << std::endl;
  }
};

template <int... T>
struct wrapper {
  base<T...> a;
};

int main()
{
  wrapper<2, 3> x;
  return 0;
}
```

Knowing in advance that all template parameters of `base` are `int`, I use `template <int...T>` in the declaration of `wrapper`. This allows a limited flexibility, for instance I could define some default values for the template parameters of `base`, without modifying `wrapper`.

However, if `base` depends on an arbitray list of type and non-type template parameters, how can I pass the template parameters of `wrapper` to `base`?

For instance, if I know that all template parameters of `base` can be implicitly converted to int (without loss!), I could define `wrapper` as in the following program

```
#include <iostream>

template <int i, bool j>
struct base {
  base()
  {
    std::cout << "i is " << i;
    std::cout << " j is " << (j ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
  }
};

template <int... T>
struct wrapper {
  base<T...> a;
};

int main()
{
  wrapper<2, true> x;
  return 0;
}
```

But if `base` depends at the same time on type and a non-type template parameters as in the following program, it is apparently not possible to simply pass the template parameters of `wrapper` to `base`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class U, int i, int j>
struct base {
  base()
  {
    std::cout << "i is " << i;
    std::cout << " j is " << j << std::endl;
  }
};

template <class... T>
struct wrapper {
  base<T...> a;
};

int main()
{
  wrapper<int, 2, 3> x; // Error!
  return 0;
}
```

This program does not compile, because the compiler expects types for `wrapper`.

Is there a way to write a class `wrapper` that "pass" its template parameters to a member of type `base`, *whatever they are*?

The idea would be to have a generic code for `wrapper` which does not need to be modified if, say, the template signature of `base` changes.

Comment: Is `base` under your control? Because if it is, we can constraint its template parameter list to make `wrapper` easier to write.

Comment: AFAIK it can't be done. The compiler has to know, for each identifier, whether they are type names or an expression. This is also why you have to write `typename` for dependent names.

Comment: @NickyC Yes, I program myself ```base```. If possible, I would like to retain the flexibility of expanding/changing ```base``` without the need to update ```wrapper```.

Comment: Don't use non-type parameters for `base`, wrap everything is `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: "Is there a way to write a class wrapper that "pass" its template parameters to a member of type base, whatever they are?" - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to Your problem. It is not very elegant and requires specific approach but works in the cases You want:

```
template <class U, class i, class j>
struct base {
  base()
  {
    std::cout << "i is " << i::value;
    std::cout << " j is " << j::value << std::endl;
  }
};

template <class ...T>
struct wrapper {
  base<T...> a;
};

int main()
{
  wrapper<int, std::integral_constant<int, 2>, std::integral_constant<int, 3>> x; //no error now!
  return 0;
}
```

With C++17 it can be less verbose:

```
template<auto val>
using value_wrapper = std::integral_constant<decltype(val), val>;

int main()
{
  wrapper<int, value_wrapper<2>, value_wrapper<3>> x; //no error now!
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *This has of course its limitations* In technical terms, it doesn't work. *base depends on an arbitrary list of type and non-type template parameters* This box is not checked, and it's the *only* box.

Comment: @n.m. You are right, I got question wrong. I am fixing answer atm

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I will mark it as a solution