# c++ auto for type and nontype templates

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

In c++17 `template <auto>` allows to declare templates with arbitrary type parameters. Partially inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51056414/8769985) question, it would be useful to have an extension of `template <auto>` that captures both type and nontype template parameters, and also allows for a variadic version of it.

Are there plans for such an extension in the next c++20 release? Is there some fundamental problem in having a syntax like `template<auto... X>`, with `X` any type or nontype template parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are there plans for such an extension in the next c++20 release?

No.

> Is there some fundamental problem in having a syntax like `template<auto... X>`, with `X` any type or nontype template parameter?

It would be a totally new concept in the language - having a name refer to *either* a type *or* a value in the same place. So it'd come with all sorts of additional questions - and probably additional language features to check if `X` is a type or not.

The syntax likely *cannot* be `template <auto... X> struct Y { };` since that syntax already has meaning and means a bunch of values and `Y<int>{}` is ill-formed.

There are definitely places where such a thing would be useful though. A proposal would just have to address these issues.

Comment: We could totally remove `template` keyword and replace with auto since autos are translated as template in the backend anyway

Comment: I expect you to now make this proposal

Comment: @SombreroChicken Don't hold your breath.

Comment: I am now dead .

Comment: @texasbruce: The correct syntax would be `auto <auto> auto { auto };`. I believe, however, we should work at making C++ less verbose by using: `car <car> car { car };` instead. Won't somebody think of the keyboards?

Answer (score 1):

The big issue with trying to do something like that is grammar. Template parameters state up-front whether they are templates, types, or values, and the most important reason for this is grammatical.

C++ is a context-sensitive grammar. That means that you cannot know, just from a sequence of tokens, what a particular sequence of tokens means. For example, `IDENTIFIER LEFT_PAREN RIGHT_PAREN SEMICOLON`. What does that mean?

It could mean to call a function named by `IDENTIFIER` with no parameters. It could mean to default initialize a prvalue of a class named by `IDENTIFIER`. These are rather different things; you might conceptually see them as similar, but C++'s grammar does not.

Templates are not macros; they're not doing token pasting. There is some understanding that a piece of code in a template is supposed to mean a specific thing. And you can only do that if you at least know what kind of thing a template parameter is.

In order to retain this ability, these "omni template parameters" cannot be utilized until you actually know what they mean. So in order to create such a feature in C++, you would need to:

1. Create a new syntax to declare omni template parameters (`auto` isn't going to fly, as it already has a specific meaning).
2. Provide a syntax for determining what kind of thing an omni template parameter is.
3. Require the user to invoke that syntax before they can use such parameter names in most ways. This would typically be via some form of specialized `if constexpr` block, but pattern matching proposals represent an interesting alternative/additional way to handle them (since they can be expressions as well as statements). And expansion statements represent a possible way to access all of the omni parameters in a parameter pack.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see how it would be useful that a template argument could be dynamically either a type or a value? The code statements that use types are very different to those that which use constant values introduced through the template argument.

The only way would be a big "if constexpr" which would make it pointless in my view.

Ok, having looked more closely at the referenced question, I guess there is room there for generically pass-through wrapping the various explicit base template implementations that use different parameter orderings. I still fail to see a huge benefit. The compiler errors when it goes wrong are going to be unfathomable, if nothing else!

I remember being told that overloading and templates were going to rid the world of the unfathomable error messages generated from macros. I have yet to see it!

Comment: I have to admit that I can't think of a complete use case. But considering that there exists contexts where both a type or a value would be valid (`sizeof` comes to mind) I can imagine that someone somewhere would have liked this feature at some point.

Comment: @PasserBy Hmm, but asking the question "Is this a specialisation for that" can be answered much more simply by the compiler that already knows, surely?