# why don't the template parameters participate to the class definition/redefinition

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

why is the following code forbidden:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct A
{

};

template <class T>
struct A// error: different template parameter => redeclaration
{

};
```

knowing that we can be verbose to express the same idea:

```
template <class T>
concept C_TypePack = T::is_type_pack_concept;

template <class... Types>
struct TypePack {static constexpr bool is_type_pack_concept = true;};

template <class T>
concept C_NonTypePack = T::is_non_type_pack_concept;

template <auto... NonTypes>
struct NonTypePack {static constexpr bool is_non_type_pack_concept = true;};

template <class T>
concept C_TemplatePack = T::is_template_pack_concept;

template <C_TypePack TTypePack, C_NonTypePack TNonTypePack>
struct TemplatePack {static constexpr bool is_template_pack_concept = true;};

template <C_TemplatePack TP>
struct A;

template <std::size_t N>
struct A<TemplatePack<TypePack<>, NonTypePack<N>>>
{

};

template <class T>
struct A<TemplatePack<TypePack<T>, NonTypePack<>>>
{

};
```

my question is: why not allowing this kind of code:

```
template <any>
struct A;

template <std::size_t N>
struct A<N>
{

};

template <class T>
struct A<T>
{

};
```

I don't care about the "it's written in the law" aspect. I just want to see where is the ambiguity from a compiler point of view. By analogy, the template functions are just fine.

EDIT: thanks to the comment from  n. 'pronouns' m., here is a workaround using std::array as a non type (tuple works too):

```
#include <array>

// type spe

template <auto Val>
struct A;

template <auto Size>
requires (std::is_same_v<decltype(Size), std::size_t>)
struct A<Size>
{

};

template <auto SizePack>
requires (std::is_same_v<typename decltype(SizePack)::value_type, std::size_t>)
struct A<SizePack>
{

};

// var spe

struct Foo
{
    template <auto Val>
    static consteval auto initBar()
    {
        if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<decltype(Val), std::size_t> )
            return 5.;
        else if constexpr ( requires{std::is_same_v<typename decltype(Val)::value_type, std::size_t>;} )
            return -5;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    template <auto Val>
    static constexpr auto bar = initBar<Val>();
};

int main()
{
    A<std::size_t(42)> a0;
    A<std::array<std::size_t, 1>{42}> a1;
    A<std::array<std::size_t, 2>{42, 43}> a2;

    Foo::bar<std::size_t(42)>;
    Foo::bar<std::array<std::size_t, 1>{42}>;
    Foo::bar<std::array<std::size_t, 2>{42, 43}>;

    return 0;
}
```

The question remains the same though.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941023/c-auto-for-type-and-nontype-templates

Comment: My 2c: a universal type/non-type parameter would be useful for specialization, but fundamentally a template parameter is a placeholder for something in the code. Where could you substitute both a type and a non-type value in valid code (sizeof and typeid excluded)?

Comment: @parktomatomi: thanks for the comments. I am designing a multi-dimensional array and i have several begin functions taking a size_t (sub dimension iter) or a pack of size_t (custom iter) as template. it's fine to call them begin and think about a same feature but the returned iterators are type aliases which cannot be called Iterator with different definitions.

Comment: _"By analogy, the template functions are just fine."_: function templates, and functions in general, overload. Class declarations do not overload.

Comment: Why is a single size a value, but a pack of sizes a type?

Comment: the single size is the dimension of the sub array (knowing that each template size has a rank) but the size pack specifies the ranks in order (the first one will be ranked 0 in the new array) so it's not the same thing. And i need a pack (edit: a class with variadic size_t + array introspection) because I use variadic sizes just after to fix the non extracted ranks.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it specifies. Why do you need a type there? What does your type contain that a value cannot provide? A value can be of `std::tuple` or `std::array` type.

Comment: It looks like an XY problem to me, and seems off-topic: the choice made in the language design is in this case fairly arbitrary and is not going to change. But you're focused on the language minutiae while you should be asking questions about what you're really trying to do, as it's extremely likely (almost a given) that there are idiomatic solutions, or at least idiomatic pathways to a solution.

Comment: @Unslander Monica: There is always a solution. In my case, I can use different names for each type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specialization of template functions and specialization of template types is very different.

Functions participate in overload resolution.  Overload resolution is an extremely complicated and bug-causing part of the C++ standard.  It "works like magic" because a lot of work was done to make it work, and it still behaves in ways surprising to most when it interacts with template code.

Template functions have no partial specialization, only full specialization; and specialization only changes the body used, it never changes which is selected.  Having two different ways of changing which implementation is used interacting would be insanity.

On the other hand, template types use a different way to do selection.  Here, partial and full specialization is used, overloading is not.

Specialization is a kind of subtyping.  The primary template determines what the arguments passed are, and the specializations don't.  The specializations simply *match* against the arguments of the primary template.

Your change would introduce a new set of different primary specializations.  The rules for selecting which template you are specializing would have to be changed and made insanely more complex, and working out which template you are specializing for a programmer would also be harder.

```
template<class T>
struct A;
template<int x>
struct A;

template<class T, class U>
struct A< T::template apply<U> > {};
```

quick, which template did I just specialize, `A<int>` or `A<class>`?  Now, I now, but how many people are going to be surprised by this?  A lot.

...

The second problem has to do with checking things earlier.

```
template <any>
struct A;
```

now when someone does a `A<T::template apply<U>>` you cannot check to see if you screwed up types-vs-values until far later in the process.

What more

```
template<any x>
struct A: B<x> {};
```

now we have to parse the body of `A<x>` both under the assumption that `x` is a type and a value and a template.  Is it an error if only 1 or 2 or 0 of them would work for a given statement?

How about

```
template<any x>
struct A {
  int y = x<3-x::green>;
};
```

if `x` is a type, `x::green` makes sense, but now `x<?>` only makes sense if `x` is a template.  Do you do 3 passes, one with each assumption?

template parsing is already slow and costly and complex.  Making it more complex is a really, really hard sell.

Comment: wow, thanks for your very nice answer ! You have a point considering that template specialization cannot be changed for fun with types without being changed for functions too (orthogonality). Looking at the end of your answer, i would not allow such a feature to behave like a type/non type template argument. The whole point if I understand correctly is "different primary specializations". I trust you when you say it would be complex and error prone, but let's talk about it in a few years xd. Thanks again for these compelling arguments.

Comment: In fact, I think that if constexpr / the concepts / the requires constraints should definitely be involved in the type overloading to completely remove the template specialization. With gcc 8.1 and -fconcepts, I was able to disambiguate the specializations with the constraints but now with gcc 10 (c++20), I have to specialize at least one type (non type or constraints do not participate anymore) so I systematically add an enum as integer_constant, deduced from the previous template arguments. Just to say that concepts are everything during the function overloading and not with types.